# T-SQL apply where clause to function fields not working

Tags: t-sql

I'm having a hard time filtering this view by CreateDate. The CreateDate in the table is in the following format: 2013-10-14 15:53:33.900

I managed to `DATEPART` the year month and day into separate columns, but now it's not letting me use my `WHERE` clause on those newly created columns. Specifically, the error is "Invalid Column Name CreateYear" for both lines. What am I doing wrong here guys? Is there a better/easier way to do this than parse out the day, month, and year? It seems overkill. I've spent quite a bit of hours on this to no avail.

```
SELECT convert(varchar, DATEPART(month,v.CreateDate)) CreateMonth, 
       convert(varchar, DATEPART(DAY,v.CreateDate)) CreateDay, 
       convert(varchar, DATEPART(YEAR,v.CreateDate)) CreateYear, 
       v.CreateDate, 
       v.customerName 

From 
   vw_Name_SQL_DailyPartsUsage v  

full outer join 
   ABC.serviceteamstechnicians t on v.TechnicianNumber = t.AgentNumber 

full outer join 
   ABC.ServiceTeams s on t.STID = s.STID

 where 
    CreateYear >= '02/01/2018' 
 and 
    CreateYear <= '02/20/2018'
```

Comment: PSA: [ISO date format](https://xkcd.com/1179/). Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference an alias from the select in the where

Even if you could why would you expect year to be '02/01/2018'

Why are you converting to varchar

```
where year(v.CreateDate) = 2018
```

or

```
select crdate, cast(crdate as date), year(crdate), month(crdate), day(crdate)   
from sysObjects 
where cast(crdate as date) <= '2014-2-20'
  and cast(crdate as date) >= '2000-2-10' 
order by crdate
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, DATEPART(month,v.CreateDate)) CreateMonth, 
       convert(varchar, DATEPART(DAY,v.CreateDate)) CreateDay, 
       convert(varchar, DATEPART(YEAR,v.CreateDate)) CreateYear, 
       v.CreateDate, 
       v.customerName 
From  vw_Name_SQL_DailyPartsUsage v  
full outer join 
   ABC.serviceteamstechnicians t on v.TechnicianNumber = t.AgentNumber 
full outer join 
   ABC.ServiceTeams s on t.STID = s.STID
where CreateDate BETWEEN '20180102' and  '20180220';
```

More info about the logical query processing is that you cannot refer to a column alias at `SELECT` in the `WHERE` clause without using a subquery/CROSS APPLY.

Comment: you mean YYYYMMDD correct? I just tried it and it still returns the same incorrect value